# java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java

I'm getting this error in this line of code:

```
for (int i = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size; i < size; i++)
```

why is this happening?

Comment: Your `size` seems to be zero.

Comment: Because `size` is 0.  `%` involves division, since it essentially gives you the remainder when you divide two numbers.  So `x % 0` gives you a division-by-zero exception just like `x / 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The % operator returns the remainder after dividing the first number by the second number. If the second number (in your example `size`) is zero, then you will get a divide by zero `ArithmeticException`.

The key is to check if `size` is zero before performing this loop, and take the appropriate action.