# How to fix divide by zero exception?

Tags: java, exception, divide-by-zero

It's a problem on [Sphere Online Judge (SPOJ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) for prime generator.

Input: number `t` of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n.

Output: For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n.

I have made prime[0] and prime[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) as -1.

```
    int range[][] = new int[t][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)     //take t ranges
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            range[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)                       
    {
        int prime[] = new int[range[i][1]+1];
        for(int k = 2; k <= range[i][1]; k++)
        {
            prime[k] = k;
        }
        prime[0] = -1;
        prime[1] = -1;
        for(int k = 2; k <= range[i][1]; k++)
        {
            for(int m = k + 1; m < range[i][1]; m++)
            {
                int x = prime[k];
                if(prime[m] % x == 0)
                {
                    prime[m] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried solving it by the sieve of eratosthenes. The output is:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226863/java-lang-arithmeticexception-by-zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226863/java-lang-arithmeticexception-by-zero)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArithmeticException divide by zero occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997474/arithmeticexception-divide-by-zero-occasionally)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a divide by zero exception because a statement in your program is attempting to divide a value by a value of zero and this is not allowed in Java or any other programming language that I have knowledge of.

There are two things you can do, (1) check the value of the divisor and if it is zero then do not do the divide or (2) catch the exception using a try/catch.

See [Java if vs. try/catch overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621762/java-if-vs-try-catch-overhead) as well as [Using try-catch java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644397/using-try-catch-java)

Looking at your code, I am not sure where the divide by zero is happening though it may be this area where you are using the modulus operator (`%`) to check if the remainder of a division is zero:

```
for(int m=k+1; m<range[i][1]; m++)
{
    int x = prime[k];
    if(prime[m] % x == 0)  // use modulus operator to check the remainder
    {
        prime[m] = 0;
    }
}
```

You may want to do something like:

```
for(int m=k+1; m<range[i][1]; m++)
{
    int x = prime[k];
    if(x == 0 || prime[m] % x == 0)  // use modulus operator to check the remainder
    {
        prime[m] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: "this is not allowed in Java" - it is allowed for `double` - [JLS 15.17.2. Division Operator /](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2): "The result of a floating-point division ...: Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thank you for the clarification as to a special case. This is `int` however the rules on floating point you referenced are new to me. I don't do much with `double`. What is signed infinity?

Comment: `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, some *bit-patterns*  that represent positive infinity or negative infinity, similar to `Double.NaN` that represents Not-a-Number (e.g `0.0 / 0.0`) [also valid for `Float`]